# If I only have a few trees, will furniture always spawn in them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing a couple different trees per day will have a random furniture item (makes sense, right?). However searching all trees in my current town is a pain as they're spread far and wide.

If I were to cull the majority of non-fruit trees in favor of fruit trees and a small, condensed patch of normal trees, will furniture always spawn in the small group? Will I get less furniture this way or are there other reasons I should avoid this strategy?

Comment: Animal Crossing : No Leaves

Comment: I was just wondering about this while playing Wild World yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you want 17 regular trees in town to maximize harvesting of bells and furniture.

10 will have bells. 5 usually have bees. 2 will have furniture. If you have fewer than 17 the spawn balance is out of whack.

There is no issue with planting an easily-shaken cluster of trees. I would suggest making sure they are planted in a way that will allow them to grow.

[Are there any spacing rules for trees?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120685/are-there-any-spacing-rules-for-trees)

This is a great guide on how to (and how not to) plant.