# Is there a minimum spacing planted trees need to grow?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Does this game use the [New Leaf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120685/are-there-any-spacing-rules-for-trees) rules?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not [quite like New Leaf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120693/21177) but back to that in a sec.

Yes, you need space all around the tree/sapling, as in it can't be up against a building, right next to the slope to the beach, or even on that peninsula jutting out to the right on the island. A tree that cannot grow in that spot will just remain a stunted sapling.

A good way to test whether a tree can grow in that spot is to dig up a sapling from elsewhere and try to plant it in the target spot (rather than planting the seed or fruit). The hole won't let you plant the sapling if it's a bad location.

But back to that New Leaf stuff, the weird issue of tree spacing (in which [the tree in the middle of a group of trees wouldn't grow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120693/21177)) has been resolved:

[image: holes]

[image: saplings in holes]

[image: full trees grow]

Comment: Hmm, in my experience I needed the trees to have 1 space inbetween them horizontally, but 2 spaces vertically. Your pictures show 1 and 1. What did I do wrong?

Comment: A small exception to the building rule is that you _can_ build fences directly next to trees

Answer (score 4):

Yes, new leaf rules still apply, you need space all around for a tree to exist. even if you uproot the whole thing using hunger, it wont let you replant the tree if there isnt room.