# If I have only a few available spaces, will those spaces always spawn buried objects?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've been using patterns to make paths through out my village, just to spice up things and stop grass deterioration. With so many patterns, flowers, and bushes littering the once mostly open field, it's gotten me wondering the title question.

[Similar in vein to trees](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120252/if-i-only-have-a-few-trees-will-furniture-always-spawn-in-them?rq=1), if I placed enough paths and flowers, over the entire map, except about 10 or so spaces. Would those 10 spaces contain the 3-4 daily fossils, daily pitfall seed, and random daily gyroids? Or would they just "spawn" under something else and not show up for the day?

Answer (score 3):

The items would spawn under the pathways you have placed.
I also want to let you know that placing tiles does *not* stop grass from deteriorating. It's a common rumor.

See more about grass deterioration here:
http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Grass_deterioration

Comment: Here's a bit more info on the underground spawns:   On average, three fossils can be found in the town per day, though in Animal Crossing: New Leaf there is a maximum of 5 to 6 a day. However, in a town overrun with weeds or covered with patterns, there is less space for a fossil to be underground (a fossil cannot be under rocks, where a flower or tree is, etc.) and the player may not find some or any that day. Other items may also be buried underground.   http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Fossil

Comment: As the question now links to your answer regarding trees, I have removed that part of of this answer.